# SQL server licenses/prizes (on dedicated web server)

Tags: sql-server, hosting

Hi I bought my own dedicated server to host my websites.
I want to use SQL server as database platform.
However.. de licensing options are not transparent
Can someone help me ?

What I found until now :

**2005/2008 express version**
 - Free
 - Limited to 1CPU/1GIG MEM/4GB filesize

What are the other options ?

Answer (score 1):

There are two separate issues.  First is the product you have.  Second is the license.

Products:

1. SQL Express (free)
2. SQL Developer (under US$50)
3. SQL Workgroup
4. SQL Standard
5. SQL Enterprise

The products vary by features, including things like the maximum size database they support.

Next is licensing:

1. CAL (user or device)
2. per-CPU
3. Free (only for SQL Express)
4. Single developer (only for SQL Developer)

You can use SQL Express in a public-facing web site for free.  The other products all require per-CPU licenses in that scenario.  CAL licensing is appropriate when the number of users is small, well-known, and limited -- such as Intranet apps.

You can't ever use SQL Developer in a live application; it's licensed for a single developer only.

Answer (score 0):

SQL server is licensed in 3 ways:

- Server plus user CAL (Client Access Licence)
- Server plus Device CAL (Client Access Licence)
- per CPU

I am guessing that your web site is going to be accessed by users who are not employed in your company (it is not an internal web site). Then you need a per CPU licence.

Comment: I host websites from my dedicated server.
Which version of SQL server do you use and what do you pay per month ?